# django jquery autocomplete search box not displaying results

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I went through a few resources online to make use of `jquery` `autocomplete` to populate my search box.

However, as I type into the `search box`, instead of returning the search results, a `No Results` is being returned.. Another problem is that, this `No Results` is not displayed as the normal drop down below the `search box`. Instead, it appears as text below the `search box` instead.

Any thoughts?

**add_new_schedule.html**

```
<!-- jquery, jqueryui, bootstrap4 cdn are used in the headers -->

<input class="form-control" id="id_test" name="test">    <!-- this is the search box -->
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_test').autocomplete({
        source: "",
        minLength: 1,
        autoFocus: true,
    });
});
```

**views.py**

```
import json

...
...

def add_new_schedule(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        if request.GET and request.is_ajax():
            q = request.GET.get('term')
            print(q)
            student_object = Student.objects.filter(first_name__startswith=q)
            results = []
            for r in student_object:
                results.append(r.first_name)
            data = json.dumps(results)
            print(results)
        else:
            data = 'fail'
        mimetype = 'application/json'
        return render(request, 'static/html/add_new_schedule.html')
```

At this stage, as I type into the `search box`, `print(results)` will print out a list of the possible matches from the `Student` database. However, this result is not being fed back into the `search box`...

**urls.py**

```
path('schedule/add-new-schedule/', views.add_new_schedule, name='add_new_schedule')
```

Comment: Can you double-check your indentation in the code snippet for views.py?  Something weird is going on with `if request.user.is_authenticated`.  It also looks like you're not returning `data` or `mimetype` anywhere, and I'm not sure if that is the actual bug or a copy-pasty error :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out about the indentation of views.py. I've amended it. Regarding the returning of `data` or `minetype`, i'm actually not sure how this should be returned to `jquery`'s `source` for it to be displayed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, you're only ever returning HTML from your view.  What you need to do is to have a way of returning the JSON `data` that you've created.

It looks like you're already branching on whether or not the request is AJAX.  So all you need to do is return some JSON at the end of that branch:

```
def add_new_schedule(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        if request.GET and request.is_ajax():
            q = request.GET.get('term')
            print(q)
            student_object = Student.objects.filter(first_name__startswith=q)
            results = []
            for r in student_object:
                results.append(r.first_name)
            return JsonResponse(results, safe=False)

        else:
            return render(request, 'static/html/add_new_schedule.html')
```

[JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#id4) automatically sets the mimetype and encodes to JSON.  The `safe=False` allows you to pass a list rather than a dictionary.  According to the Django docs, passing lists (which became Javascript Arrays) was originally considered unsafe, but Javascript fixed the issue in 2011 so it's probably fine to not worry about now.

Technically you don't need the last `else`, you could just dedent the `return render...`.  It's really a stylistic choice.

As far as the error message's location on the webpage, is it possible you're either not including some required CSS or happen to have your own CSS with the same class names?

Comment: Thanks Dave. After adding your code, as I type in the `search box`, the `autocomplete helper` says that there are `x` number of results, but these results seem to appear as an empty bullet point (just 1 bullet point even though there are 3 results). Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm.  I'll admit it's been a long while since I used jquery-ui-autocomplete.  And had about as much trouble with it as you are having ;).  So the helper says there are 3 results but you're only getting one bullet point?  Is it possible you have 3 results in the DOM but they're all overlapping?  If you inspect that bullet point with your browser's dev tools, can you see anything interesting?

Comment: I did a google search. I had to do several things. But mainly, its got to do with the way the package is structured before sent to `JsonResponse`. `autocomplete` is really picky.. So the data have to be in a format like `[
   {"data":6,"value":"Lulu"},
   {"data":14,"value":"Luis"}
]` or `[{'label': 'something'}]`